# window.postMessage behaves abnormal on Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I use window.postMessage in Chrome Extension Content script:

```
function() {
   window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        console.log(event);
   }, false);


   window.postMessage({ type: \"FROM_PAGE\"}, "*");}
```

The abnormal behavior is that the first time I call this function, console print event once; the second time I call, console print twice; the third time, three times.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are adding a **new** EventListener **each** time you **call the function.**

Thus every of your added EventListener's receives the Message posted by `postmessage` and then does

`console.log(event)`

So the first time you call you function. You `EventListeners` function,gets executed only once because only **1** `EventListener` is attached to the DOM that calls `console.log`

On the second time there are two `EventListeners` that execute `console.log`  and so on...

You should attach you `EventListener`

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
...
}
```

outside your function.
And do only the `window.postMessage({ type: \"FROM_PAGE\"}, "*");`
part inside the function

Comment: Thank you, I was doing something similar and your answer saved me!